# Convert file from .doc to .docx when uploading file to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

The Microsoft Graph Api gives users the possibility to convert files to other formats when downloading these files. The problem I am having is that I have a lot of users with old `.doc` files stored and these users should be able to edit these in the browser but SharePoint will create a new file with the same name only in `.docx` format and keep the old file on the drive.

I want users to be able to edit these files so I do need the `.docx` format. The problem is I want only 1 version of the file but in `.docx` format. Is it possible to convert the format of my files when uploading `.CreateUploadSession(par)` using Microsoft Graph Api?

If not is there a better way than doing the following:

1. uploading the `.doc` file,
2. downloading the file using the `.docx` format,
3. uploading this `.docx` file and
4. deleting the old `.doc` file